# Ring homomorphism with field as image, is the pre-image also a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. $R,S$ are both integral domains. Suppose $S$ is a field, then is $R$ also a field?

A possible useful fact: A finite integral domain is a field.

Comment: In fact, since you assume $f$ is surjective, $R$ is a field iff $f$ is injective iff $f$ is an isomorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $R$ need not be a field. For instance, if $R$ is the polynomial ring $S[x]$, then the map $R\to S$ given by $f(x)\mapsto f(0)$ is a surjective ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Simple family of counterexamples:  let $R = \Bbb Z$, the integral domain of integers.  Let $S = \Bbb Z_p$ for any prime $p$, and let $f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z_p$ be the usual projection given by $f(z) = z (\mod p)$.  All the hypotheses of the question are satisfied, but $R = \Bbb Z$ is not a field.  Generalization:  let $R$ be any non-field integral domain with a *proper* maximal ideal $M$, that is, $\{0\} \ne M \ne R$.  (This may be a bit redundant if one defines a maximal ideal to be a *proper* subset of $R$, but bear with me, if you please.)  Then $R/M$ is a field and the natural map $f:R \to R/M$ is surjective.  So we see there are *very many* counterexamples.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***